# Initialize string enum member with other string enum member

Tags: typescript

I noticed this [sentence](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#string-enums), `"In a string enum, each member has to be constant-initialized with a string literal, or with another string enum member."`, then I writed some examples.

Following is one of examples.

```
enum RIGHT {
  VALUE = 'Right',
}

enum Direction {
  Up = "UP",
  Down = "DOWN",
  Left = "LEFT",
  Right = RIGHT.VALUE,  // Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.
}
```

```
// additional example
enum Direction {
  Up = "UP",
  Down = "DOWN",
  Left = "LEFT",
  // Reference itself member.
  Right = Direction.Up,  // Computed values are not permitted in an enum with string valued members.
}
```

This is strange about `"or with another string enum member."`.

Then, following is another example, I removed other members besides `Right`.

```
enum RIGHT {
  VALUE = 'Right',
}

enum Direction {
  Right = RIGHT.VALUE // Why is it right?
}
```

Enum members are always `readonly`, why does referenced to it become a computed value?? They can't be modified, So I think the first example should be correct..

Comment: Note that the particular restriction you're talking about will be removed when TS5.0 introduces [some improvements to enums](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0-beta/#all-enums-are-union-enums).  This isn't directly what you're asking about, but it's probably relevant.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah, it is really relevant. I'll skip this concept and wait for the release of TS5.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See ts [PR](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/50528).

> An enum member has a unique and opaque enum member type when it is initialized by a non-constant expression. **Non-constant initializer expressions must be assignable to `type number` and are not permitted in const enum declarations.**

Following is correct.

```
enum RIGHT {
  VALUE = 20,
}

enum Direction {
  Up = 1,
  Down = 2,
  Left = 3,
  Right = RIGHT.VALUE,  // correct!
}
```

`E.C` denotes a unique enum member type representing the value computed by **the non-constant initializer expression.** This unique type is assignable to type `number`, **but otherwise incompatible with other types.**

```
enum E {
    A = 10 * 10,  // Numeric literal enum member
    B = "foo",    // String literal enum member
    C = bar(42)   // Opaque computed enum member
}
```

Comment: Please use TS5.0!

Answer (score 0):

It is simply a TypeScript implementation detail for enums. All enum members are considered either constant or computed. The definitions for this can be found in the documentation. The section on this is  [Computed and constant members in Enums](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#computed-and-constant-members) (emphasis mine)

> Each enum member has a value associated with it which can be either constant or computed. **An enum member is considered constant if**:

> It is the first member in the enum and it has no initializer, in which case it’s assigned the value 0:

> It does not have an initializer and the preceding enum member was a numeric constant. In this case the value of the current enum member will be the value of the preceding enum member plus one.

> The enum member is initialized with a constant enum expression. A constant enum expression is a subset of TypeScript expressions that can be fully evaluated at compile time. An expression is a constant enum expression if it is:
>
> - a literal enum expression (basically a string literal or a numeric literal)
> - a reference to previously defined constant enum member (which can originate from a different enum)
> - a parenthesized constant enum expression
> - one of the +, -, ~ unary operators applied to constant enum expression
> - +, -, *, /, %, <<, >>, >>>, &, |, ^ binary operators with constant enum expressions as operands

> **In all other cases enum member is considered computed.**

When you remove the other string members in your enum, your enum suddenly only has non-computed members in it

Comment: [official example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYOwrgtgBAYglgG2AQQMauAZ01A3gKCigHpipUB7ETAFwEMQaoJgIAjYAJ00KgDkqwADS8ASsDoATKAF4oARigAeJVADMIogHVOcGsFkLlqgEyao4qTr0G5l6QB8o1-edLkKEAA5h90luxcvADihgBE8iZqYQB0SCAA5jQAFiIAvkA). There are two types(const and computed) of enum at the same time. What does is `Suddenly only has non-computed members in it' mean?